# Bluetooth keyboard connects but doesn't work

Tags: wireless, keyboard, bluetooth

My HP TouchPad wireless bluetooth keyboard connects to `input service` in blueman, but it won't work as a keyboard in ubuntu.

Blueman receives data from the keyboard however when I mash buttons, since the transfer rate goes up to about 5kb/s instead of 0 when idle.

How can I tell ubuntu that the keyboard is a keyboard and it should listen to the input?

Edit: 5/6/13: This is still an issue, and the dozens of various things I've tried over the past weeks haven't helped. Only restarting works (it has this problem after standby).

Edit: 7/4/13: Updating ubuntu to 13.04 fixed the issue for me. The script posted [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/bluez/+bug/268877) in the top comments also worked.

Answer (score 1):

Updating to 13.04, or using the script on [this bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/bluez/+bug/268877) page both resolved the issue.